# Text doesn't break line, but it overflowed by tot px on the right

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I created a widget that contains some columns and rows.
The second label in the last Column not create new line, insted overflow by 108px to the right.

I'm using Flutter 3.7.12, Dart 2.19.6, DevTools 2.20.1.
Iphone 13 pro emulator and also Iphone 12 Pro device.

This is the widget (the last "Text" not break the line, I wrote a comment on the Text line):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project/ui.dart';

class SzCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? imageUrl;
  final String? iconLabel;
  final Widget? icon;
  final String label;
  final String? description;
  final dynamic onInfoAction;
  final String? textColor;
  final bool? showArrow;

  const SzCard({
    super.key,
    required this.label,
    this.description,
    this.iconLabel,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.icon,
    this.textColor,
    this.showArrow,
    this.onInfoAction,
  });

  @override
  State<SzCard> createState() => _state();
}

class _state extends State<SzCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext parentContext) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          if (widget.onInfoAction != null) {
            widget.onInfoAction();
          }
        },
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: HexColor("#F2F1FA"),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 15, bottom: 15, left: 10, right: 10),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      if (widget.imageUrl != null)
                        Image.network(widget.imageUrl!),
                      if (widget.icon != null)
                        Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                child: widget.icon!)),
                      if (widget.iconLabel != null)
                        Container(
                            height: 50,
                            width: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                color: Colors.white),
                            child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                              widget.iconLabel!,
                              // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  color: widget.textColor != null
                                      ? HexColor(widget.textColor!)
                                      : HexColor("#E6E5F0")),
                            ))),
                      if (widget.imageUrl != null ||
                          widget.icon != null ||
                          widget.iconLabel != null)
                        const SizedBox(width: 15),
                      if (widget.imageUrl == null &&
                          widget.icon == null &&
                          widget.iconLabel == null)
                        const SizedBox(width: 50),
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(widget.label,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                color: widget.textColor != null
                                    ? HexColor(widget.textColor!)
                                    : Colors.black,
                              )),
                          if (widget.description != null)
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 7,
                            ),
                          if (widget.description != null)
                            // this text not break
                            Text(
                              widget.description!,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                color: widget.textColor != null
                                    ? HexColor(widget.textColor!)
                                    : Colors.black,
                              ),
                              softWrap: true,
                              maxLines: 2,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  if (widget.showArrow == true)
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_right_alt,
                      size: 30,
                    )
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

[image]

UPDATE:

I already tried to wrap Text or Column inside a Expanded or Flexlibe, but didn't work.

Attach error:
[image]
[image]

Comment: you need to wrap your `Text` with `Expanded` widget

Comment: I already tried, but when I use Expanded or Flexible the app have an error:
The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
szCard.dart:92
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

Comment: Ok, just for testing make a `Row` with two `Text` children: a very short "short" and very long "long long long long (repeated 20 times)", now run it, it will show the yellow-black error at the end of long text, now replace `Text('long ...')` with `Expanded(child: Text('long ...'))`

Comment: @pskink Outside the widget it work, only inside this widget not working

Comment: do you need those two rows? cannot it be just one?

Comment: yes those rows are 2 different allignments

Comment: @pskink I tried with only one row in the widget and the problem persist

Comment: then try to simplify your UI more, until you find which widget is making problems, or try that `Row` which works (with `Expanded`) and try adding more and more widgets

Comment: @pskink I tried, row --> row --> column --> expanded show the error
I think that to use expanded I can't nest row and column togheter

Comment: use the most simple row with expanded, run it, then add one more widget and after adding always run it, so you are sure what widget is making problems

Comment: Row --> Row --> Expanded broke the code, so it's true, I can't nest row and columns and use expanded

Comment: this is a version with two nested rows `class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Row(
children: [
Text('short 1'),
Expanded(
child: Row(
children: [
Text('short 2'),
Expanded(child: Text('long ' * 20)),
],
),
),
],
);
}
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code to fix the problem. You have wrapped a `Padding` widget with a `Container` widget which is unnecessary as `Container` widget already has `padding` property. Apart from that you have placed a `Row` with a `Row` widget, which is causing the UI overflow issue. You have to wrap the `Row` with `Expanded` widget as shown below:

```
class SzCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? imageUrl;
  final String? iconLabel;
  final Widget? icon;
  final String label;
  final String? description;
  final dynamic onInfoAction;
  final String? textColor;
  final bool? showArrow;

  const SzCard({
    super.key,
    required this.label,
    this.description,
    this.iconLabel,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.icon,
    this.textColor,
    this.showArrow,
    this.onInfoAction,
  });

  @override
  State<SzCard> createState() => _state();
}

class _state extends State<SzCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext parentContext) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          if (widget.onInfoAction != null) {
            widget.onInfoAction();
          }
        },
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: HexColor("#F2F1FA"),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15, left: 10, right: 10),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      if (widget.imageUrl != null)
                        Image.network(widget.imageUrl!),
                      if (widget.icon != null)
                        Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                child: widget.icon!)),
                      if (widget.iconLabel != null)
                        Container(
                            height: 50,
                            width: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                color: Colors.white),
                            child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                              widget.iconLabel!,
                              // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  color: widget.textColor != null
                                      ? HexColor(widget.textColor!)
                                      : HexColor("#E6E5F0")),
                            ))),
                      if (widget.imageUrl != null ||
                          widget.icon != null ||
                          widget.iconLabel != null)
                        const SizedBox(width: 15),
                      if (widget.imageUrl == null &&
                          widget.icon == null &&
                          widget.iconLabel == null)
                        const SizedBox(width: 50),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(widget.label,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  color: widget.textColor != null
                                      ? HexColor(widget.textColor!)
                                      : Colors.black,
                                )),
                            if (widget.description != null)
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 7,
                              ),
                            if (widget.description != null)
                              // this text not break
                              Text(
                                widget.description!,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  color: widget.textColor != null
                                      ? HexColor(widget.textColor!)
                                      : Colors.black,
                                ),
                                softWrap: true,
                                maxLines: 2,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                if (widget.showArrow == true)
                  const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_right_alt,
                    size: 30,
                  )
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked.
U saved me hours of debugging